# Receive UDP Broadcast fails when change wifi Status Android

Tags: android, sockets, udp, wifi, broadcast

I have a receive routine inside AsynTask:

```
                    byte[] message = new byte[1500];
                    s = new DatagramSocket(null);
                    s.setReuseAddress(true);
                    s.bind(new InetSocketAddress(dataclass.getDataclass().GGGPort));
                    p = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
                    s.setSoTimeout(500);
                    s.setBroadcast(true);
                    dataclass.getDataclass().setGoOut(true);
                    s.receive(p);
```

This code works perfect to receive UDP broadcast packets in Android, but we have one problem:
When in Android is receiving UDP packets and I turn off Access Point (no more packets arrives) and after I turn on the access point, I have the same problem : Timeout.

In this situation, If i disable wifi and enable wifi all works another time...

Anyone with the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to re-create and re-bind the receiving socket each time the device's connection status changes.

Comment: Hi Remy, thanks for your reply. I do it ! But it doesn't work.  As you can see in my code, I do it for each receive / timeout that I catch.

Comment: Why are you creating a new socket every time you do a new receive? You should create the socket once and receive on it multiple times, then you can recreate that socket only when actually needed. Think about what would happen if a UDP packet is sent to you but you do not have a socket actively listening for it at that moment. It would get discarded. So if you try to receive a packet that was already discarded, that could account for your timeout issue.